# .htaccess redirect except path segment + different redirect for the rest - what's wrong?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

What is wrong with my code? Note: As both domains share same .htaccess, the host must always match ".de" (requests which have already been redirected to ".com" domain should be ignored).

```
# 1. Redirect all non DE stuff to other domain (.com)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/de/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(dev)\.(domain)\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1.%2.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]

# 2. Redirect only DE stuff (below /de/) and stay inside same domain
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/de/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(dev)\.(domain)\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^de/(.*)$ https://%1.%2.de/$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

Second set seems fine. Although the first RewriteCond doesn's seem to be neccessary (why?).

But the first set also redirects "domain.de/de/thing" to anything wild ("domain.com/index.php"). Although it should only match "^/de/"?

Update: It seems impossible using automated rules (see comments). Two rulsets are required. One for explicitely redirecting all EN path segments, another for redirecting all DE path segments:

```
# 1. Redirect all non DE stuff to other domain (.com)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(english-segment-1|english-segment-2|english-segment-3)($|/) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(dev)\.(domain)\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1.%2.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]

# 2. Redirect only DE stuff (/de and below /de/) and stay in same domain
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/de($|/) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(dev)\.(domain)\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^de($|/)(.*)$ https://%1.%2.de/$2 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

Comment: Can you clarify this `But first set also redirects "domain.de/de/thing" to anything wild` ?

Comment: It redirects to „domain.com/index.php“. But shouldn’t it match at all?

Comment: 2nd rule redirects `domain.de/de/thing` to `domain.de/thing` and then 1st rule will trigger because there is no `/de/` at the start.

Comment: 1st set also redirects to "domain.com/index.php" if 2nd set is disabled! Why? You're rght with the rest, can't work. But is there any possibility at all to achieve my issue?

Comment: There are conflicting requirements. If someone requests `domain.de/foobar` then how will you know if it supposed to be redirected to `.com` or it is a redirect resulting from 2nd rule?

Comment: OK, i was blind. Sorry. So the only possibility is to explicitely match against all concrete first level EN path segments (which are luckily only a few) and redirect them to the COM domain + redirect the DE path segment using the existing set.

Comment: Yes that approach will certainly work